# Best silverlight video technique for playing movies

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I was wondering if anyone can give me some insight on what is the prefered best option for playing a video in a Silverlight MediaElement.  Right now I am using a direct link to a .wmv file on an mms server but the location is inconsistent and occasionaly locks up my ui when I try to load the video.

When this happens the storyboard animations that take place that is supposed present the video freeze up until the video is loaded then the animation catches up and jumps to the end.  Looks really bad.

I have the option for smooth streaming as well.  Just curious if there is a prefered best way to present video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a minimum you should not be starting your storyboards until the MediaOpened event has fired.  And yes, smooth streaming would probably present the best user experience.